# How can I list an entire MySQL row as string

Tags: mysql, string

how can I select (in MySQL) and entire row, not column, and output it as a string in Java?

The table is as follows.

```
id | username | note | issuer
=============================
1  | James    | text | Matthew
2  | Callum   | text | Corey
3  | Rebecca  | text | Tyler
```

Output example

**2 Callum text Corey**

Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 2`? This is the most basic SQL you can get by? what have you tried?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, I would like to have it output as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat()`

```
select concat(id,' ',username,' ',note,' ',issuer) as record
from your_table
```

Comment: So is this returned as a string?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM <tablenem> WHERE id = 2;
```

for complete records:

```
SELECT * FROM <tablenem>;
```

also if he need the value without any separater :

```
SELECT CONCAT(id,surname,note,issuer) FROM <tablenem>;
```

with separator like space:

```
SELECT CONCAT(id,' ',username,' ',note,' ',issuer) as <alias>
FROM <tablename>;
```

Comment: ok then he need to execute only,,SELECT * FROM <tablenem>